# Android some time my code give not accurate distance in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, locationmanager, locationlistener, android-fusedlocation

I have android app in which i am getting distance travelled speed and time some time the app works fine but sometime the app does not give accurate result i am using fused API in locationService class. any suggestions are welcomed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a real android phone on your test and your code is 100% correct maybe the problem might be with the device itself. Have you turned  gps high accuracy on? Have you tested your application with another phone?

Comment: yep iam using Real android device. some times its accurate but some time    suddenly distance goes to 400 meter or 800 m

Comment: Maybe you should try using a different device just to make sure it isn't a device problem and start looking in the code